# How would I do a proper fadein for dynamic content refreshing with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a .txt file that I need to include into a page, that gets dynamically updated every 5 seconds, so I need to refresh it via ajax, so that the updated content can be seen without refreshing the page. I want to do it so it fades into the div, with every 5 second update.

Currently Im doing it like this, which is pretty ugly looking

```
function getSearches() {
      $("#latest_searches").animate({ 
        opacity: 0.3
      }, 1000 );

$("#latest_searches").load("_latest_searches.php", '', callback);
}

function callback() {
  $("#latest_searches").animate({ 
        opacity: 1
      }, 1000 );

setTimeout("getSearches();", 5000);
}

$(document).ready(getSearches);
```

Comment: could you explain what the actual problem is a bit more clearly?

Comment: the title should describe the problem you're trying to solve. also, since it's tagged 'jquery' you don't need to say jquery in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to create a [Digg Spy-like](http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/jquery_spy2/) effect, check [this demo](http://leftlogic.com/jquery/spy.html).

Check also this article/screencast: [Simple jQuery Spy Effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-jquery-spy-effect/)

Comment: Nice link - might have to incorporate that on SO somewhere!